# How can I remove an image by clicking on it in Fabricjs?

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

I want to have two event handlers.
one is when I click on the canvas based on mouseX an mouseY an image appears at a certain position (snap to grid).

The second is when I click on the same image that appeared I want this image to be removed.

The first event handler is implemented and work well the second doesn't work how can I make this happen?

Also I guess that when I want to remove my image the first event handler triggers and add a new image it's a vicious circle.

Here is my `addImage()` function:

```
function addImage(spaceX, spaceY, mouseX, mouseY, sizeX, sizeY, url) {
  //spaceX/Y is the size of my grid
  //mouseX/Y are the coordinates of my mouse
  //sizeX/Y is the size of my canvas
  //url is the url of my image.
  fabric.Image.fromURL(url, function(oImg) {
    var divX = sizeX / spaceX;
    var resX = mouseX / sizeX * divX;
    var indW = Math.trunc(resX); //X index in the grid
    var divY = sizeY / spaceY;
    var resY = mouseY / sizeY * divY;
    var indH = Math.trunc(resY); //Y index in the grid
    oImg.top = indH * spaceY;
    oImg.left = indW * spaceX;
    oImg.scaleToWidth(spaceX);
    oImg.scaleToHeight(spaceY);
    oImg.selectable = false;
    //this is my non-working function to remove my image.
    oImg.on('click', function() {
      canvas.getActiveObject().remove();
    })
    canvas.add(oImg);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
oImg.on('mousedown', function (){
  canvas.remove(this);
})
```

use `mousedown` event for object.

***DEMO***

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');
fabric.Image.fromURL('http://fabricjs.com/assets/pug.jpg', function(oImg) {
    oImg.on('mousedown', function (){
      canvas.remove(this);
    })
  canvas.add(oImg);
});
```

```css
canvas{
 border:2px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/kangax/fabric.js/master/dist/fabric.js"></script>
<canvas id='canvas' width=500 height=400>
```

Comment: Thanks I've already solved my problem. You're solution doesn't solve the problem of multi-fired handlers. Also the syntax for removing the object was bad because of the FabricJS version I'm using. Anyway thanks for the answer

Comment: @JSmith this is only method to [remove](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Canvas.html#remove), and `object.remove()` is deprecated in newer versions.